# How to reset settings sync?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I had a VS Code install on which I had built up various settings and customizations over the span of two years.

I recently reinstalled Windows and decided to set up VS Code without syncing settings, and making a fresh start. Now I want to upload the new settings to my Microsoft account but not download the old ones. How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code has this built-in. Attempt to sync settings after making new settings locally and VS Code will ask you how to deal with any merge conflicts.

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/11bcd1e/comment/j9x6ca7/?context=3